# How can I get an array which is a modification of another whilst keeping the original?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create two arrays `a` and `b`, then create an array `c` which is the same as `a` but the first column is pulled from `b`. At the end there should be 3 different arrays.

Something like the following:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1]])
b = np.array([[0, 0]])

c = b
c[:, 0] = a[:, 0]

print(a, b, c)
```

Should outputs:

```
[[1 1]] [[0 0]] [[1 0]]
```

But I am getting:

```
[[1 1]] [[1 0]] [[1 0]]
```

For some reason, modifying `c` also modifies `a`.

Comment: `c = b.copy()` - then do what you want with `c`

Comment: `c = b` *doesn't create a copy*.  read the following https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: "For some reason modifying c also modifies a" *because `c` and `b` are names referring to the same object*.

Answer (score 3):

You can perform a copy of the object by using `.copy()` like so:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1]])
b = np.array([[0, 0]])

c = b.copy() # or b.deepcopy()
```

From the documentation:

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create
> bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are
> mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one
> can change one copy without changing the other. [The copy] module provides
> generic shallow and deep copy operations...

Link: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html